# Does mounting a disk image make any state changes to the file itself?

Tags: windows, macos, filesystems, disk-image

Say you take a disk image file and you "mount" it, is it possible for that file to be changed in anyway by the very act of mounting it?

(I'm mainly interested in Mac and Windows, but also POSIX.)

Comment: FYI, you could easily check for yourself.  Run a hash check (MD5, SHA, etc) on the disk image before mounting the drive, then after.

Comment: @Keltari, Yea it doesn't change for my particular test. hence the question.

Comment: If it doesnt change, then there is your answer.  However, your particular test might not be the right "question"

Comment: @Keltari, ?͏͏͏͏

Answer (score 2):

Absolutely. Mounting an image is exactly like mounting a drive to the VFS, the only difference is where the VFS points its routines at. If the filesystem driver doesn't have write support (e.g. ISO9660 or DMG) then there's no way to change the image, but things such as the ext* dirty bit will still be frobbed.

Comment: Does this include read-only mounts (like what Mac does by default when you doubleclick it)? ¶ Say you mount an image as "read-only", can a virus somehow bypass that?

Comment: I don't know enough about OS X to be able to answer that.

Comment: I mean talking about "read-only mounts" in general?

Comment: If you e.g. `mount -o ro` then the VFS will prevent writing to the image. A R/W remount can be attempted though.

Comment: If it's a journalling file system, couldn't there be journal entries even when mounted in read-only mode?

Comment: They could exist, but they can't be replayed to the filesystem.

Answer (score 2):

The act of actually mounting it won't change the image, however part of the greater mounting process may include file system checks etc which could change the image.   I guess if you are concerned about this you would mount an image Read-Only - but then you won't be able to mount it.

Comment: Re "mount an image Read-Only - but then you won't be able to mount"; ??

Comment: Of-course you will - assuming the filesystem is clean.

Comment: I mean your above statement contradicts itself... ¶ Separately, what do you refer to by the "greater mounting process"?

Comment: Mounting is the process of connecting a block device and making it available to the OS. When mounting a disk, the OS will recognise the type of filesystem and - and this is what I mean by greater mounting process - and could - depending on the file system type and mount options - kick off a process to clean the filesystem - but this later function is not intrinsic to the mount procedure.